# multiple email adresses and password for a single user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a school project and my idea is to have a site where you can register an account, add a couple of users to that account and then calculate their monthly shared expense debt, e.g. User A pays 500 on groceries and user B only pays 250. This gives User B a debt of 125 to user A that month.

My problem is that I want to separate the accounts with the users. Now I have a setup of a table called Accounts with email and password and then I have a users table with particular user information. I want several people to be able to log in to the same account using different credentials.

Users table

```
ID, Name, Account_id etc.
```

Accounts table

```
ID, Email, Password, date_added, date_updated etc.
```

What is the best approach of doing this? Is it to have a cross-table called UsersForAccounts or do I specify several account_ids in the Users-table?

Comment: Why not make something like a `group_id`, where each `account_id` is part of one (or more) `group_id` values?

Comment: If I pay 500$ and you 250$, I expect you to have a debt of 250$ actually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't think of it as several users on one account. You would think of it as several user accounts that share a common group setting.

So you have a user's table as you may expect - each with its own values for that person, obviously.

Then you have a related table that shares the details for the group. Let's use a fraternity or something as an example.
SO you have Pi Phi as a group name. Within that are Users A, B and C. 
A very very basic table structure might look like this:

```
Users: id, email, password, name, group_id

Group: id, name
```

So a user would - by this setup - have a relation to only one group. You could make that a relational table so a user can have many groups if you want.

The general idea here is that you use the group as a separate connection point to the user and not necessarily several users that access with the same account.

If that is unclear, feel free to ask and I may update

Comment: Oh, I see where you are going with this. I'll sketch something up and get back to You with the results! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a structure such as in the **Users** Table:

```
ID, Name, etc.
```

And in the **Accounts** table use simplest:

```
ID, Email, Password, date_added, date_updated, User_ID, etc
```

This is called Many to One relationship, and is ideal to your case.

A small tip i can pass to you is use LOWERCASE to ALL your fields, or in special to the first character of the name of the field, with an excerpt for "ID" (that is only a acronym (or similar) to *Identification*)

In an basic example, the **Users** table has the fields:

```
ID, name, etc.
```

And **Accounts** table the structure above:

```
ID, email, password, date_added, date_updated, user_id
```

This can't help much in a short time, but it can help you, and very much, at use of the database with PHP.